# Actions must be plain objects in redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I have a feeling I'm using `mapToDispatchProps` incorrectly here:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        resetLoginForm() {
            dispatch(reset("login"))
        },
        resetLoginFailState() {
            dispatch(resetLoginFailed);
        }
    }
}
```

It's working for `resetLoginForm`, meaning, I can access `this.props.resetLoginForm()` just fine. But when I added `resetLoginFailState`, I get an error when the action is called: `Actions must be plain objects`

The actual action does return a plain object so I'm not sure what the issue is there:

```
export const resetLoginFailed = () => {
    return { type: RESET_LOGIN_FAILED }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
resetLoginFailState() {
   dispatch(resetLoginFailed);
}
```

You are dispatching a function - literally. You forgot to execute it to dispatch a **redux action**:

```
resetLoginFailState() {
   dispatch(resetLoginFailed());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Actions must be plain objects, why?

Because you passed a function to dispatch, You need to call that function, then only it will return the object.

Write it like this:

```
resetLoginFailState() {
    dispatch(resetLoginFailed());        // notice ()
}
```